# RouterLink in Angular using Javascript

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to use a javascript method similar to `routerLink` in HTML but using Javascript.

I have tried with `window.location` but the result is not the same since this command refreshes the website to jump from one URL to another. Is there any possibility to jump from a component to another one as `routerLink` does (not refreshing)?

**Solution**

I was asking for `router.navigateByUrl('/url')`

Answer (score 0):

The `routerLink`'s directive internal implementation doesn't use the `window.location` API, but the `window.history` API, the `window.history.pushState()` function to be more precise ([Source](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/cf0968f98e844043a0f6c2548201f3c0dfd329a7/packages/platform-browser/src/browser/location/browser_platform_location.ts#L60)).

Same goes for every SPA Framework.

Answer (score 0):

It's `window.location.hash` that you can change without reloading. That can be used to create an SPA as well if you don't want to mess with `history.pushState()`

```js
window.addEventListener( 'hashchange', event => {
  console.log( `should render page: ${ window.location.hash }` )
});
```

```html
<a href="#/home">Home</a>
<a href="#/page1">Page 1</a>
<a href="#/page2">Page 2</a>
<a href="#/page3">Page 3</a>
```

This does have other downsides compared to `history.pushState()`, like search engine optimalization and such. But it's the simplest method to do single page app routing. So kinda depends on what you're building if it'll suffice or not.

If you're using angular though, just use the routing angular provides.